# Sphinx searchd.service for multiple conf files

Tags: sphinx

How i can add multiple conf files on searchd.service so when the server restart or reboot to auto loads the conf? right now is just 1 conf

```
[Unit]
Description=SphinxSearch Search Engine
After=network.target remote-fs.target nss-lookup.target
After=syslog.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=sphinx
Group=sphinx
# Run ExecStartPre with root-permissions
PermissionsStartOnly=true
ExecStartPre=/bin/mkdir -p /var/run/sphinx
ExecStartPre=/bin/chown sphinx.sphinx /var/run/sphinx
# Run ExecStart with User=sphinx / Group=sphinx
ExecStart=/usr/bin/searchd --config /home/www/websites/_sphinx/web1/web1.conf
KillMode=process
KillSignal=SIGTERM
SendSIGKILL=no
LimitNOFILE=infinity
PIDFile=/home/www/websites/_sphinx/web1/log/searchd.pid

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
Alias=sphinx.service
Alias=sphinxsearch.service
```

Im using Sphinx version sphinx-2.2.11-1.rhel7.x86_64.rpm on centos 7.3

Answer (score 1):

Currently Sphinx does not support multiple config files or `include` directive.

But you can use a workaround: if a config file starts with a shebang like `#!/bin/sh`, then Sphinx will launch the specified interpreter and read its output as the configuration info.

So you can use this:

```
#!/bin/sh
cat /path_to_sphinx_conf_files/*.conf
```

Just make sure that your config files are named in proper order if they depend on one another.